# Webpage is not fit properly inside webview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I am simply creating a `UIWebView` in my iPad screen.

`UIWebView` frame : x=60,y=53,w=258,h=274

Now i am simply displaying Google.com in the webview and webview is showing it.

But the site is not fit in to my webview i.e. i have to scroll horizontally and vertically to see the whole webpage in side my webview.

I have also tried

```
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;

webView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But no result.

Comment: i am not sure about webView.contentMode, but just have webView.scalesPageToFit=TRUE; should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement UIWebViewDelegate then asign it to your controller.

The interface would look kind of like this:

```
@interface WebView : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView *_webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Then the implementation:

```
@implementation WebSection

@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (id)initWithId:(short)sid
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    }

    return  self;
}

@end
```